# How does having child contents affect CSS positioning? Or does it?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative;">
    <input id="input" class="form-control" />
    <div id="icon" class="oi oi-chevron-bottom" style="position:absolute;" />
    <div id="list" style="position:absolute;">123</div>
</div>
```

I am having troubles understanding why the above code lines produce something like this:
[image]

My current understanding is that `position:absolute;` means positioning to the closest parent element.

So I thought the `<div>` with `id="list"` will be placed in the same place as the `<div>` with `id="icon"` because they share the same parent element.

But apparently that is not the case.

Why isn't the `<div>` with `id="list"` placed the same way as the `<div>` with `id="icon"`?

What concepts am I missing. (Currently I don't know what I don't know...)

Any reading materials or answers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you need to define the position in the absolute div, doing top:0 for example